# Error compiling code with openCV

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, cmake

I am following the direction from this website http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html to compile a code in which I use openCV. When I create and compile the code for the first time I had no problem, but when I change the code of the .cpp file and then try to compile it again, the "cmake ." gives me the following errors:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:DisplayImage
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "DisplayImage".
```

I know that the changes that I made to the original code work because I created a new folder and follow the same directions with the new code, and I have no problem, but once again when I run "cmake ." again, the same error appears.

How can I change the code of the .cpp file and then compile/"make" without any error? I want to avoid having to create a new folder with the new code every time I change something in the .cpp file.

Thanks in advance for any help someone could provide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run "cmake ." only one time. If you change your .cpp file, then you simply need to run "make" again.

If you really want to run "cmake ." again for the sample DisplayImage code, you can simply delete the DisplayImage executable ("rm DisplayImage") and then you should be able to run "cmake ." again.

(Perhaps someone with more cmake experience could share why this is so...)